# continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

My book (Calculus by Howard Anton) says that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$. But $\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt{h}$ is defined easily whereas  but $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \sqrt{-h}$ cannot be defined. So if limits of both sides isn't equal then how can we say it's continous at $x=0$?

Comment: Often authors write "continuous" when they mean "continuous on its domain."

Comment: Consider the *domain* of $\sqrt{x}$. There is nothing left of $0$ in the domain, so no left-side limit at $0$ can be defined. Therefore the function is continuous at $0$ since the only one-sided limit that applies exists.

Comment: When a function is not defined (perhaps because it does not make sense to or simply because it hasn't been defined yet) to the (left) rigth of a number continuous usually is understood to mean (left) right continuous; i.e. that the (left) right limits exist.

Comment: We say that a function $f$ defined on an interval $[a,b)$ is continuous at $a$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to a^{+}}f(h)=f(a)$. Here $f(h)=\sqrt{h}$ and $[a,b)=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Guest $\chi_{[0,1)}$ is not continuous at $0$...

Comment: @mrob `Often authors write "continuous" when they mean "continuous on its domain."` I'd leave the "*often*" part out. A function cannot be continuous *outside* its domain, ever.

Comment: @mathbeing I should have wrote right-continuous.

Comment: @Guest Yes. It is actually clear what you meant, but I pointed that out so the OP don't get it wrong.

Comment: @mathbeing By the way, my definition would only apply to the restriction of $\chi_{[0,1)}$ to, say, $[0,1)$ and *that* restriction is continuous at $0$ according to it. But OK, I should have wrote $f:[a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ since the way I wrote it may mean that $f$ could be defined on some superset of $[a,b)$